# Google Map Places javascript text search : can't get radius to work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I need to get google places results (javascript, not places api) to display a list of places based on a text search.

Everything is working fine excepts radius parameter as you can see on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53eqf8du/2/).

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
});
var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '5000',
    query: cat_search
};
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(request, callback);
```

If you click on "Restaurant" it is almost ok, if you click on "Peintre" it get results over 5000 radius and if you click on "Fastfood et Snack" results are going crazy, results from 70000 m radius are returned.

NOTE: I removed my google map key from the script url on jsfiddle. The results are the same with the key. The key is not revelant with google map javascript api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#TextSearchRequest), the location and radius are used to bias the results, not restrict them.  If you don't want to display the results outside of the radius, you can remove them from the output displayed.

The documentation states:

> **bounds** Type:  LatLngBounds Bounds used to bias results when searching for Places (optional). Both location and radius will be ignored if bounds is set. **Results will not be restricted to those inside these bounds; but, results inside it will rank higher.**
>
> **location** Type:  LatLng|LatLngLiteral The center of the area used to **bias** results when searching for Places.
>
> **radius** Type:  number The radius of the area used to **bias** results when searching for Places, in meters.

**code snippet which removes results outside of the specified radius**

```js
var map;
var service;

function initMap(param_lat, param_lng, cat_search) {

  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(param_lat, param_lng);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 5000,
    query: cat_search
  };


  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var max_iteration = (results.length < 5) ? results.length : 5;
      var resultCount = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(results[i].geometry.location, pyrmont) < request.radius) {
          console.log(results[i]);
          var request2 = {
            placeId: results[i].place_id
          };
          service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
          service.getDetails(request2, callback2);
          resultCount++;
        }
      }
      if (resultCount == 0) {
        $("#res").prepend("No Results inside search area");
      }
    } else {
      $("#res").prepend("No Results, status " + status);
    }
  }
}



function callback2(place, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var photos = place.photos;
    if (!photos) {
      temp_var = "<img width='30' src='" + place.icon + "' />";
    } else {
      temp_var = "<img  src='" + photos[0].getUrl({
        'maxWidth': 30,
        'maxHeight': 30
      }) + "' />";
    }
    temp_var += place.name;
    temp_var += " :" + (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(new google.maps.LatLng(50.4167, 4.4333), place.geometry.location) / 1000).toFixed(1) + " km [" + place.geometry.location.lat() + ", " + place.geometry.location.lng() + "]<br />";
    $("#res").prepend(temp_var);
  }
}

function toRad(Value) { // Converts numeric degrees to radians
  return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry"></script>
<a onclick="initMap( 50.4167, 4.4333,'Fastfood et Snack');">Fastfood et Snack</a>

<br />
<a onclick="initMap( 50.4167, 4.4333,'Restaurant');">Restaurant</a>

<br />
<a onclick="initMap( 50.4167, 4.4333,'Peintre');">Peintre</a>

<div id="map" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="res"></div>
```